# Right click in nightwatch is not working .mouseButtonClick('right')

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, nightwatch.js

```
.click('#gridW33F8AEBDB6D146F085CCBF0BF28D63B4 > div.ag-root-wrapper.ag-layout-normal.ag-ltr > div.ag-root-wrapper-body.ag-layout-normal > div.ag-root.ag-unselectable.ag-layout-normal > div.ag-body-viewport.ag-layout-normal.ag-row-no-animation > div.ag-center-cols-clipper > div > div > div.ag-row.ag-row-no-focus.ag-row-even.ag-row-level-0.vitara-row.vitara-grid-row-even.ag-row-position-absolute.ag-row-first > div:nth-child(1) > div')
      .mouseButtonClick('right')
      .pause(1000)
      .keys(browser.Keys.DOWN_ARROW)
      .pause(1000)
      .keys(browser.Keys.DOWN_ARROW)
      .pause(1000)
      .keys(browser.Keys.DOWN_ARROW)
      .pause(1000)
      .keys(browser.Keys.DOWN_ARROW)
      .pause(1000)
      .keys(browser.Keys.DOWN_ARROW)
      .pause(1000)
      .keys(browser.Keys.RIGHT_ARROW)
      .pause(1000)
      .keys(browser.Keys.RIGHT_ARROW)
      .end()
      .pause(3000);
```

**i am using code like this my nightwatch version is 1.7.11 but contextMenu button is not working for me**

Answer (score 0):

`.mouseButtonClick()` suppose to click at the current mouse coordinates set by `moveTo()` or `moveToElement()` method.

**Example 1:**

```
browser.moveToElement('css selector', elementName, 1, 1);
browser.mouseButtonClick('right'); // or use number 2 in the argument
```